combine each row in table to all row in another table
I have two tables like this (mysqli):
Products



ID
Product




1
Product No.1


2
Product No.2


3
Product No.3



Grade



ID
Grade




1
grade 1


2
grade 2


2
grade 3



I need to combine each row in table Products to all row in table Grade and result is like this:



Product
Grade




Product No.1
grade 1


Product No.1
grade 2


Product No.1
grade 3


Product No.2
grade 1


Product No.2
grade 2


Product No.2
grade 3


Product No.3
grade 1


Product No.3
grade 2


Product No.3
grade 3



How can I do this?
I tried Join but it did not work.

"I tried Join but..."  Please include in your question what your tried.

You start with two tables having 3 records. The end result has 9 records. That why this is named a cartesian product

Use CROSS JOIN
  Select P.Product, G.Grade
   From  Products P
      CROSS JOIN 
         Grades G
  Order by P.Product, G.Grade;

Sample Code: db<>fiddle
